# Tool to flatten yaml

Tags: string, yaml

Is there a tool to flatten yaml structure like this:

```
foo:
  bar:
    baz: true
```

into this:

```
foo.bar.baz = true
```

not sure what is this syntax name

context: I need this for hcl, setting a lot of values like this:

```
set {
  name = "foo.bar.baz"
  value = false
}
```

this is for helm-provider in terraform, cannot use directly use json or yaml, have to set properties that you want to change one by one (i need to disable lots of stuff to check why it's not working).

Comment: Is the 2nd format intended to be a java properties file? You can use [yamldecode](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/yamldecode) to deserialize yaml.

Comment: oh no, need to create a lot of `set { name = "foo.bar.baz", value = false }` on hcl file XD

Comment: Do you mean [this hcl](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl)? Can't you just convert your YAML to JSON and submit that?

Comment: yep, parse, recursively printing then `| grep valueIwantToChange`

Comment: Are you trying to convert a helm values file into a format for the terraform helm provider?  If so, you can specify yaml as `values = []` instead of `set {}`. See the doc here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release

Comment: Using `values` means you do not need to convert the yaml to a different format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Andrey Kislyuk's `yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) to get all paths for the boolean values in the input document, for each path, join the path elements with dots, and then output each dotted path with the values found at that path.

```bash
yq -r '
    paths(type == "boolean") as $p |
    [ ($p | join(".")), getpath($p) ] |
    join(" = ")' file
```

Example input document:

```yaml
foo:
  bar:
    baz: true
  baar:
    baz: false
```

Resulting output:

```
foo.bar.baz = true
foo.baar.baz = false
```

To only get the paths ending with a key named `enabled` that has a `true` boolean value (as shown [in an example elsewhere](https://github.com/kokizzu/yamlflatten#usage)):

```bash
yq -r '
    (
      paths(type == "boolean" and .) |
      select(last == "enabled")
    ) as $p |
    [ ($p | join(".")), getpath($p) ] |
    join(" = ")' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't find anything, so I'll made it myself '__')

https://github.com/kokizzu/yamlflatten